# File header comment block breaks RequireJS Optimizer r.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

Given the following AMD module (messages.js):

```
/*************************************************************************
 * Copyright blah blah blah
 *
 *************************************************************************
 *
 * @description
 * Super detailed description here...
 * 
 * @author
 * Eric Steele
 *
 *************************************************************************/
define(['angular'], function() {
  return "here's a message!";
});
```

With a RequireJS configuration that looks something like this...

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: 'javascripts',
  paths: { 
    'angular':  '../bower_components/angular/angular.min',
    'messages': './shared/services/messages',
  }
});
```

And the following r.js configuration:

```
({
  baseUrl: "javascripts",
  mainConfigFile: './javascripts/requirejs-config.js',
  optimize: 'none',
  optimizeCss: "none",
  waitSeconds: 0,
  name: 'app',
  wrapShim: 'true',
  preserveLicenseComments: false,
  out:  './javascripts/app-built.js'
})
```

I get the following in my build output:

```
/*************************************************************************
 * Copyright blah blah blah
 *
 ******'messages',*******************************************************************
 *
 * @description
 * Super detailed description here...
 * 
 * @author
 * Eric Steele
 *
 *************************************************************************/
define(['angular'], function() {
  return "here's a message!";
});
```

As you can see, r.js has inserted the module name 'messages' inside the comment block instead of placing it as the first argument of the define() call.

If I remove the file header, the module name is properly inserted like so:

```
define('messages',['angular'], function() {
  return "here's a message!";
});
```

However, if I leave a blank line at the start of the file like so:

```
// pretend this comment is a blank line
define(['angular'], function() {
  return "here's a message!";
});
```

Then I see this in my build output:

```
'messages',
define(['angular'], function() {
  return "here's a message!";
});
```

It seems that r.js expects my define() call to be at the top of the file. Otherwise, it cannot properly insert the module name into the define().

I'm using r.js version 2.1.15. The build completes without errors.

Any idea how to fix this?

**Update 1**
I forgot to mention that the build output file contains many additional newlines in it. These added newlines disappear if I give my modules a name in the define() call. Giving them a name also fixes the insertion issue. However, I've read that giving modules a fixed name is a bad practice (r.js should generate them). So far, this seems to be the best fix, but I'd like to know why r.js is breaking in the first place...

Comment: I've got over 50 modules with comments (containing jsdoc directives) right before the `define` call and I do not get the problem you are getting. I suggest you provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that someone can download and run. (It could be put up as a repo on github or somewhere else.)